# Lenovo ThinkPad T61 drivers for Vista to Windows 7 migration

Tags: windows-7, drivers, migration

I recently installed a full version of Windows 7 on my T61. The laptop came with Vista Ultimate and I kept the special partition that keeps the original OS. While backing up my files too, I backed up the folder `C:\SWTOOLS\` which seemed to be a folder full of installers for the original system. That folder actually contained many other folders, one being `\DRIVERS\`.

When I go into Device Manager, I get yellow icon next to two instances of `Base System Device` under the `Other Devices` section. I'm not exactly sure what drivers I need to install for these generic things.

Also, I noticed when I change the volume using the buttons on my keyboard, the vol goes up or down, but doesn't have the On Screen Display. Does anyone know what specific installer will add OSD and where I can configure it in Win7 post-install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Base System Device" is the card reader (Ricoh).

however, Windows 7 should find the driver if you point to the folder you have backed up, it will go through all sub directories, or get the latest 32-bit version [here](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-67791).

the On Screen Display will be installed with the **[Hotkey Driver](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-68000)**.

Comment: Wow you're fast. Thanks so much! That's exactly what I needed. I don't know why I didn't just point it to the folder and let it do the work... should have known...

Comment: you're more than welcome. but you should get the hotkey driver from their website, it supports windows 7.