# Lenovo T61 mute button and On Screen Display mute indicator doesn't work in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, migration, osd

This quesion is a follow-up to a [two-part question I previously had](https://superuser.com/questions/81202/lenovo-thinkpad-t61-drivers-for-vista-to-windows-7-migration). It's in regards to my On Screen Display settings on my Lenovo T61.

I recently reformatted my Lenovo T61 and put Windows 7 Professional on it. I backed up the original Vista driver installers that were at `C:\SWTOOLS\` so even though I didn't use them for Windows 7, I have them just in case. I had quite a bit of trouble getting my On Screen Display to show me my volume adjustments. I read a [forum post](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T61-and-prior-T-series-ThinkPad/T61P-on-screen-display/td-p/95109;jsessionid=50CAACAFD7EA0F3A9E5550CDB49134EE) at Lenovo and basically [discovered](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T61-and-prior-T-series-ThinkPad/T61P-on-screen-display/m-p/117381#M33689) there are several programs that need to be executed to turn the OSD on. They are:

- c:\drivers\win\hotkey\osd\lvosdsvc.exe
- c:\drivers\win\hotkey\osd\tponscr.exe
- c:\drivers\win\hotkey\osd\tposdsvc.exe

So I added shortcuts to these three exe's into my startup folder and my up/down volume issue was fixed. But then I realized the mute OSD and the mute button itself **doesn't** work. So I'm wondering how I can get the mute button to work. I believe I've download the [correct OSD driver from Lenovo](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-68000) so I'm a bit stumped on the mute button -- it worked in Vista!

To re-iterate, I have all of the original Vista drivers that came with the machine so if there's a specific Lenovo utility I need to install, I can most likely do it. I just need to know what to install or what utility I may not be running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the [Lenovo System Interface Driver for Windows7, Vista and XP - Notebooks](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-67228),

I have a T61P with the same video card and was experiencing the exact same symptoms.  The System Interface Driver fixed everything.

Comment: YES! That did it! Thanks so much for letting me know Scott

Comment: Worth note that this is a great solution for any lenovo notebook experiencing this issue, but that link is long-since gone to linkrot.

Answer (score 3):

Same for me. No onscreen and mute, etc. were not working. I took an extra step to check it. Did what was suggested at [Lenovo System Interface Driver for Windows7, Vista and XP - Notebooks](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-67228). That did nothing.

Then I found [Hotkey Features Integration for Windows 7 (32-bit, 64-bit), Vista (32-bit, 64-bit), XP (32-bit, 64-bit) and 2000 - ThinkPad](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-74261)  and after a restart it's cherry.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed a similar issue on my x300 running a clean install of Windows 7 x64.  Posting my fix here in case it helps you also.

- Right click on desktop background, select display resolution
- Choose "Advanced Settings"
- Click on "On Screen Display" tab

On mine, the check-box to show the OSD was unchecked, and no font size/color/etc was selected.  I checked the box and filled those in, and suddenly my mute button started working.  Weird but effective.